# project.assets.json not found

Tags: macos, asp.net-core, .net-core

I am trying to run a asp.net core 1.1 web application on a MacOS. I have downloaded all the latest versions of .NET including the SDK (currently 1.0.3)
When I run `dotnet restore` things go smoothly but when I try to build or run the app I get this error message:

```
JSON:EC json$ dotnet run
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.3/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/build/Microsoft.PackageDependencyResolution.targets(154,5): error : Assets file ‘/Users/jasonfenwick/Documents/Account Creation and Dashboard/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle/obj/project.assets.json’ not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file. [/Users/jasonfenwick/Documents/Account%20Creation%20and%20Dashboard/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle.csproj]
obj/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/EmptyCubicle.AssemblyInfo.cs(6,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name ‘System’ could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/jasonfenwick/Documents/Account%20Creation%20and%20Dashboard/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle.csproj]
obj/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/EmptyCubicle.AssemblyInfo.cs(7,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name ‘System’ could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/jasonfenwick/Documents/Account%20Creation%20and%20Dashboard/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle.csproj]
obj/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/EmptyCubicle.AssemblyInfo.cs(8,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name ‘System’ could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/jasonfenwick/Documents/Account%20Creation%20and%20Dashboard/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle.csproj]
obj/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/EmptyCubicle.AssemblyInfo.cs(9,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name ‘System’ could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/jasonfenwick/Documents/Account%20Creation%20and%20Dashboard/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle.csproj]
obj/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/EmptyCubicle.AssemblyInfo.cs(10,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name ‘System’ could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/jasonfenwick/Documents/Account%20Creation%20and%20Dashboard/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle.csproj]
obj/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/EmptyCubicle.AssemblyInfo.cs(11,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name ‘System’ could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/jasonfenwick/Documents/Account%20Creation%20and%20Dashboard/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle.csproj]
obj/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/EmptyCubicle.AssemblyInfo.cs(12,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name ‘System’ could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/jasonfenwick/Documents/Account%20Creation%20and%20Dashboard/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle.csproj]
obj/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/EmptyCubicle.AssemblyInfo.cs(13,12): error CS0246: The type or namespace name ‘System’ could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/jasonfenwick/Documents/Account%20Creation%20and%20Dashboard/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle.csproj]
obj/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/EmptyCubicle.AssemblyInfo.cs(6,55): error CS0518: Predefined type ‘System.String’ is not defined or imported [/Users/jasonfenwick/Documents/Account%20Creation%20and%20Dashboard/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle.csproj]
obj/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/EmptyCubicle.AssemblyInfo.cs(7,61): error CS0518: Predefined type ‘System.String’ is not defined or imported [/Users/jasonfenwick/Documents/Account%20Creation%20and%20Dashboard/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle.csproj]
obj/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/EmptyCubicle.AssemblyInfo.cs(8,59): error CS0518: Predefined type ‘System.String’ is not defined or imported [/Users/jasonfenwick/Documents/Account%20Creation%20and%20Dashboard/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle.csproj]
obj/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/EmptyCubicle.AssemblyInfo.cs(9,59): error CS0518: Predefined type ‘System.String’ is not defined or imported [/Users/jasonfenwick/Documents/Account%20Creation%20and%20Dashboard/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle.csproj]
obj/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/EmptyCubicle.AssemblyInfo.cs(10,68): error CS0518: Predefined type ‘System.String’ is not defined or imported [/Users/jasonfenwick/Documents/Account%20Creation%20and%20Dashboard/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle.csproj]
obj/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/EmptyCubicle.AssemblyInfo.cs(11,55): error CS0518: Predefined type ‘System.String’ is not defined or imported [/Users/jasonfenwick/Documents/Account%20Creation%20and%20Dashboard/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle.csproj]
obj/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/EmptyCubicle.AssemblyInfo.cs(12,53): error CS0518: Predefined type ‘System.String’ is not defined or imported [/Users/jasonfenwick/Documents/Account%20Creation%20and%20Dashboard/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle.csproj]
obj/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/EmptyCubicle.AssemblyInfo.cs(13,55): error CS0518: Predefined type ‘System.String’ is not defined or imported [/Users/jasonfenwick/Documents/Account%20Creation%20and%20Dashboard/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle.csproj]
obj/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/EmptyCubicle.AssemblyInfo.cs(3,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name ‘System’ could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/jasonfenwick/Documents/Account%20Creation%20and%20Dashboard/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle.csproj]
obj/Debug/netcoreapp1.1/EmptyCubicle.AssemblyInfo.cs(4,7): error CS0246: The type or namespace name ‘System’ could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [/Users/jasonfenwick/Documents/Account%20Creation%20and%20Dashboard/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle.csproj]
/usr/local/share/dotnet/sdk/1.0.3/Sdks/Microsoft.NET.Sdk/build/Microsoft.NET.Sdk.targets(92,5): error : Assets file ‘/Users/jasonfenwick/Documents/Account Creation and Dashboard/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle/obj/project.assets.json’ not found. Run a NuGet package restore to generate this file. [/Users/jasonfenwick/Documents/Account%20Creation%20and%20Dashboard/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle/EmptyCubicle.csproj]

The build failed. Please fix the build errors and run again.
```

I gathered that the program is looking for a project.assets.json file which is created when "dotnet restore" is run. And is there in the correct folder.

I have tried removing this file and re-running `dotnet restore`, thus recreating the file. But the error persists.

Comment: Try deleting the bin/ and obj/ folders in the project, and do another dotnet restore. That has fixed similar issues for me where it seemed that the files weren't restored properly.

Comment: Can you also post your `.csproj` file?  And post the output of running `dotnet restore`.  Sometimes there are errors during restore that are easy to miss.

Comment: I am having this issue as well on a Windows 2017 Host Machine build deployed to VSTS.

Answer (score 2):

Use NuGet 4.x (which is available in the NuGet Installer task in VSTS) is the recommended way to restore packages for VS 2017 projects. Reference https://github.com/Microsoft/vsts-tasks/issues/3762

Answer (score 0):

Try upgrading to Nuget 4.x, which should generate the missing project.assets.json.